# How can I run multiple modelsim instances in parallel without race conditions?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, modelsim

I want to run the same simulation with multiple parameters in parallel.
How do I do this? How can I prevent race conditions, when multiple instances try to compile to the same folder and are changing the same modelsim.ini file?

I am using QuestaSim.

I want to do something like this:

```
while ($x <= $num_processes)
  vsim -do run.do &
end
```

And starting vsim is failing for some instances for several different reasons. (Lib cannot be found, no such module)

Comment: Where do you expect race conditions? Each ModelSim instance is a separate process ... You might have problems with file overwriting but that's a different question!

Comment: The file overwriting is the race condition.

Comment: which file overwriting?  write in different files.

Answer (score 2):

[VUnit](http://vunit.github.io/index.html), a free and open source test framework for VHDL and SystemVerilog, handles this.

Below is a minimum VUnit testbench in VHDL with the addition of a `value` generic and a call to `info` (part of VUnit logging framework) to print that generic.

```
library vunit_lib;
context vunit_lib.vunit_context;

entity tb_example is
  generic (value      : integer;
           runner_cfg : string);
end entity;

architecture tb of tb_example is
begin
  test_runner : process
  begin
    test_runner_setup(runner, runner_cfg);

    info("Generic = " & to_string(value));

    test_runner_cleanup(runner);
  end process;
end architecture;
```

This testbench can be run with different generic values by defining configurations in the VUnit run script. Below is a minimum run script with the addition of three lines to create these configurations (see comment).

```
from os.path import join, dirname
from vunit import VUnit

root = dirname(__file__)

ui = VUnit.from_argv()
lib = ui.add_library("lib")
lib.add_source_files(join(root, "*.vhd"))

# Add 5 configurations with the names 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and the generic set to the corresponding value
tb_example = lib.entity("tb_example")
for i in range(5):
    tb_example.add_config(name=str(i), generics=dict(value=i))

ui.main()
```

If this script is executed with the `-p5` option VUnit will run the simulations in five different threads. The order of execution is not deterministic as can be seen in the output.

[image: VUnit output]

Disclaimer: I'm one of the authors.

Comment: What about overall performance? Using threads in Python for CPU-bound tasks do not give any advantages.

Comment: Simulators usually use just one thread so running several simulations in parallel gives close to 4x if you have a quad core

Comment: Oh, you've just invoke several instances of external simulator with different parameters.

Comment: Exactly, so you would need many simulator licenses but there are free ones that you can use.

Comment: VUnit also works together with Jenkins-CI, which allows you to run massive numbers of parallel Modelsim instances on a cluster of networked machines

Answer (score -2):

You can set parameters to a vsim call via enviroment variables.
Read them with:

```
global env; 
puts $env(RESULTFOLDER)
```

You can propagate parameters to a verilog/vhdl file with generics:

```
-Gparam=123
```

To prevent **race conditions** when running several instances of modelsim in parallel you need to take care of two things:

1. Have a seperate instance of the library folder for each instance.

   ```
   vlib work
   file rename work $RESULTFOLDER/work
   vmap work $RESULTFOLDER/work
   ```
2. Make sure to copy the modelsim.ini file before launching the process and set it seperatley for each instance.

   ```
   cp modelsim.ini $folder/modelsim.ini
   vsim -modelsimini $folder/modelsim.ini  -do run.do
   ```